# Routing + pagination in CodeIgniter - can't open first page

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have this route defined:

```
$route['search/(:any)/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)'] = "home/results/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5";
```

and my pagination in results() function:

```
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/search/'.$data['keyword'].'/'.$data['1'].'/'.$data['2'].'/'.$data['3'].'/';
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['uri_segment']=6;
```

It works great except, when I'm going back into first page from any of the next pages - url cannot be found, because when I'm typing in browser:

```
mysite.com/search/key/param1/param2/param3/0 (first page) -> works fine
```

but when I want to go to first page from:

```
mysite.com/search/key/param1/param2/param3/10 (second page) => 
mysite.com/search/key/param1/param2/param3/ (fiest page - without "0" index at the end, pagination doesn't add it at the end)
```

then URL cannot be found

Comment: For search functionality query string is the way to go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add multiple routes in order to work:

```
$route['search/(:any)/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)'] = "home/results/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5";
$route['search/(:any)/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)'] = "home/results/$1/$2/$3/$4/0";
$route['search/(:any)/(:num)/(:num)'] = "home/results/$1/$2/$3/0/0";
...
```

i think you got the message

Comment: The /0 and /0/0 are unnecessary, FYI.